# Parse.com user.SaveInBackground() updates only one field (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

Can someone help me, please?

If i write something like this:

```
ParseUser.becomeInBackground(Profile.readProfileInf(getContext(), Profile.SESSION_TOKEN, ""), new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        parseUser.put("fullname", fullnameValue);
        parseUser.saveInBackground();    
    }
});
```

Everything works fine, but when i want to update multiple fields, like:

```
ParseUser.becomeInBackground(Profile.readProfileInf(getContext(), Profile.SESSION_TOKEN, ""), new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        parseUser.put("fullname", fullnameValue);
        parseUser.put("age", ageValue);
        parseUser.saveInBackground();
    }
});
```

Nothing happens... The same problem if I use userLoginInBackground() intead of user.becomeInBackground()
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Make sure that `ParseException e` is null

Comment: @RediOne1, yes, e == null and parseUser.isAuthenticated() also returns true... it happens only when I update more than one field.

Comment: Add `SaveCallback` to `saveInBackground()` and then check `ParseException`

Comment: @RediOne1, everything is ok